# io.in(data.room).emit("group",username) not working

Tags: node.js, io, socket.io, chat

i am trying to broadcast the message in a room whenever a new user join the room,using 'socket.io' and 'node js'. Here is the relevant code where i get stuck.(what is currently happening is :

step 1: one user created the group(message get displayed in chat room "you created the room and joined it")

step 2: other user join the group(the message get displayed "joined the group" on the user who joined but not on the other user who created the group)

trying to 'emit' the message that user has joined the group as its first message on the 'chatroom', but it is not emitting the message.

tried `io.on(data.room).emit("group",...`
`socket.to(data.room).broadcast.emit(....`
`socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit(....`

*server side ->app.js*

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {


socket.on("joinGroup",(data)=>{
    console.log("room clicked server",data)
    // socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit("jgroup",{username : data.username})//not emitting to jgroup, which will show that this current user joined the group
     socket.to(data.room).broadcast.emit("jgroup",{username : data.username})
    // io.in(data.room).emit("jgroup",{username : data.username})
    //console.log(data.room)
   // console.log(data.username)
   console.log(io.sockets.name)



})
});
```

*client side ->chat.js

```
$(function () {
//make connection
console.log("hello")
var socket = io()
socket.on("jgroup",(data)=>{
    console.log("11111111111111",data.username)

    feedback.html('');
    message.val('');
    chatroom.append("<p class='message'  style='font-family:courier;'>" + data.username + " has joined the group. </p>")

})
});
```

Thanks in advance.Any help will be appreciated. Ask if not understand my problem, tried to clearly and in simple way to put my query.

Answer (score 0):

To emit to every one in a room you would call `io.to(data.room).emit("jgroup",...`

The cheat sheet here is handy https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Comment: According to the documentation `io.to().emit()` is used for emitting to a particular user. As i tried but it didn't emitting the message.

Comment: On Socket IO documentation they show the use of it here in the "Joining and leaving" section.  https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

You have to put the room name as a parameter in the to() method.